# Platform Neutral SQL Statement for INSTR or CHARINDEX

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, standards, platform-independent

I have a problem writing a SQL statement for both Oracle and MS SQL server.  I'd like to write the SQL so that it works in both.  I don't want to have to mess around with setting a database type variable and switching

I have a column of course names that have values like this:

> 9RA923.2008W
>
> 1223.200710
>
> P0033330.200901

I want to select everything right of the ".".

In oracle I am using this:

```
SELECT substr(bom_course_id, instr(bom_course_id, '.')+1) FROM ...
```

In MSSQL Server I could use this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(bom_course_id, CHARINDEX('.', bom_course_id)+1 ) FROM ...
```

Does anyone have a clever way that I can select the last characters after the dot, using the same SQL statement in either Oracle or MS SQL.

Unfortunately, I won't know how many characters there will be before or after the "."
It's not completely numeric either, I can't count on only numbers.

I really wish there was an SQL standard.

Comment: Just to be more clear, I need to split on the "." - I won't know exactly how many characters are before or after the dot.

Comment: +1 for using "platform neutral" instead of "platform agnostic."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [this link](http://sqlzoo.net/lfun), I do not see a standard way to achieve what you want to do.

```
ORACLE uses: INSTR
SQL SERVER uses: PATINDEX, CHARINDEX

ORACLE uses: SUBSTR
SQL SERVER uses: SUBSTRING
```

I could not think of a common method to obtain a character position.

A *VIEW* is probably the easiest way to proceed, or to do it *within the client application* itself.

Comment: http://sqlzoo.net/fun_position

The function "Position" would have done the trick.

Instead of forcing SQL to separate the string,  I have decided to select bom_course_id and split the string in code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered just hiding the select in a database view ?
From the application point of view, it will just be a plain, vanilla SELECT with no functions and all the database-specific stuff remains in the database.

May not suit everyone, but its an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Can you cast it to a numeric and then take just the decimal part?

Comment: No sorry, I just checked, I can't rely on the string being all numbers.  It would have worked though.

Answer (score 0):

If your regional settings are same on both databases, you may use

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(CAST(bom_course_id AS FLOAT) AS INTEGER)
```

Comment: No, unfortunately I can't rely on being all numbers.  Besides, I need the substring to the right of the "."

This would almost work:
SELECT DISTINCT bom_course_id - ( CAST(CAST(bom_course_id AS FLOAT) AS INTEGER) )

Answer (score 0):

You could write an Oracle function named RIGHT which is doing the same like the SQL Server one and then use it in your SQL.

[Here](http://www.planet-source-code.com/URLSEO/vb/scripts/ShowCode!asp/txtCodeId!1184/lngWid!5/anyname.htm) is just an example of an implementation.

EDIT: After reading your comment, a RIGHT function wouldn't be really helpful in your situation. Then you would need to map the according SQL Server functions to Oracle.